# Defining Name for Spring Cloud Stream Binding in Actuator Endpoint

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream

When using Spring Cloud Stream with RabbitMQ, it allows you to expose the /bindings actuator which provides great information about the bindings. It also exposes the /bindings/{name} endpoint to allow you to modify the state of a running binding.

Unfortunately, if you are binding multiple listeners to the same exchange, they end up getting the same name. This is with a configuration that looks like this

```
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.data-available.destination=data.topic.exchange
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.data-available.group=data.copydata.queue.mirror
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.data-available.consumer.back-off-initial-interval=2000
spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.data-available.consumer.queueNameGroupOnly=true
spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.data-available.consumer.bindingRoutingKey=data-ready
```

So if I hit localhost:8080/actuator/bindings/
I see that there is a binding named "data.topic.exchange". Is there any way to change that name or to set it to something else such as "data-available" which is the name of the binding for all other intents and purposes such as defining it in the binding bean inside my application.

Comment: It looks like a bug to me; I suggest you open a [GitHub Issue](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/issues).

Comment: Whew. I thought I was going crazy. Will do. Thanks Gary!

Comment: Not so fast. Definitely not a bug and definitely has nothing to do with Actuator, as it shows exactly what it supposed to show - binding information and not individual listeners.
Now, that we can do as a feature request but I just wanted to close the loop on the fact that it is not a bug.
I'll follow up with more on the GH issue that you have opened